# MongoDB 3.0.4 - Issue connecting from Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to a new mongodb replica set which i created on 3 VMs where it was part of another replica set from a VM as Mongo shell. I cleaned up everything in all the VMs and reinstalled MongoDB after purging everything, but still the Mongo shell throws an error pointing to old VMs:

```
2016-07-07T17:41:35.363-0700 E - [mongosMain] error upgrading config database to v6 :: caused by :: could not write initial changelog entry for upgrade :: caused by :: failed to write to changelog:
 mongos specified a different config database string : stored : old-mongodb-host1:27018,old-mongodb-host2:27018,old-mongodb-host3-h5:27018 vs given : new-mongodb-host1:27018,new-mongodb-host1:27018,new-mongodb-host1:27018
```

Where this information is stored? I also restarted all the VMs many times and it does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Ubuntu version - 12.04.4 kernel - 3.11.0-15-generic. The replica set comes up fine.

Comment: Wait a sec: you want a replset to be member of another replica set? To which benefit?

Comment: No. this is a separate replica set. I removed the 3 VMs from the old replica set (which had 6) and using them to build another replica set, Also removed one mongo shell VM from old and creating a mongo shell and trying to connect to the new set where I am getting this error.

Comment: The error message about config server upgrades relates to a sharded cluster, not a replica set. This is an old question (and old version of MongoDB) so probably no longer relevant, but if you are getting this message in MongoDB 3.0 it sounds like you've migrated your config servers to new hostnames and should follow: [Migrate Config Servers with Different Hostnames](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/migrate-config-servers-with-different-hostnames/).